# Error while concatenating keras layers: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, concatenation

I have this model, which called [Hierarchical Attention Networks](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/hierarchical-attention-networks-d220318cf87e): 
[image]

Which proposed for document classification. I use word2vec embedding for the sentences words, and I want to concatenate another sentence-level embedding at point A (see the figure).

I used it with documents contain 3 sentences; the model summary:
[image]

```
word_input = Input(shape=(self.max_senten_len,), dtype='float32')
word_sequences = self.get_embedding_layer()(word_input)
word_lstm = Bidirectional(self.hyperparameters['rnn'](self.hyperparameters['rnn_units'], return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))(word_sequences)
word_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.hyperparameters['dense_units'], kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))(word_lstm)
word_att = AttentionWithContext()(word_dense)
wordEncoder = Model(word_input, word_att)
sent_input = Input(shape=(self.max_senten_num, self.max_senten_len), dtype='float32')
sent_encoder = TimeDistributed(wordEncoder)(sent_input)

""" I added these following 2 lines. The dimension of self.training_features is (number of training rows, 3, 512). 512 is the dimension of the sentence-level embedding.  """
USE = Input(shape=(self.training_features.shape[1], self.training_features.shape[2]), name='USE_branch')
merge = concatenate([sent_encoder, USE], axis=1)

sent_lstm = Bidirectional(self.hyperparameters['rnn'](self.hyperparameters['rnn_units'], return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))(merge)
sent_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.hyperparameters['dense_units'], kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer))(sent_lstm)
sent_att = Dropout(dropout_regularizer)(AttentionWithContext()(sent_dense))
preds = Dense(len(self.labelencoder.classes_))(sent_att)
self.model = Model(sent_input, preds)
```

When I compile the above code, I get the following error:

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 3, 128), (None,
>   3, 514)]

I specified the concatenation axis=1, to concatenate on (3) the number of sentences, but I don't know why I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the shape don't match if you specify that axis. This will work if you do this instead:

```
merge = concatenate([sent_encoder, USE], axis=-1)
```

Now there is no conflict of shapes on the remaining axes

Comment: I got this error: `ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("USE_branch:0", shape=(?, 3, 514), dtype=float32) at layer "USE_branch". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_2', 'time_distributed_2']
`

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to two lines:

```
merge = concatenate([sent_encoder, USE], axis=1)
# should be:
merge = concatenate([sent_encoder, USE], axis=2) # or -1 as @mlRocks suggested
```

and the line:

```
self.model = Model(sent_input, preds)
# should be:
self.model = Model([sent_input, USE], preds) # to define both inputs
```